# Element with absolute position is cut off by other component

Tags: react-native

I have a toolbar in my RN app. That toolbar has a button that is oversized on purpose and is overflowing from the component.
The oversized button is covered by an other component in the same page.
[image]

```
  touchable:{
    backgroundColor:'#3d3d3d',
    borderRadius:27.5,
    position:'absolute',
    left:width/2 -25,
    bottom:10,
    alignItems:'center',
    borderColor:'black',
    width:55,
    height:55,
    justifyContent:'center',
  }
```

Mark up:

```
  render() {
    return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{position:'absolute', width:42,height:42,left:20,top:(height-42)/3,zIndex:3}}>
          <Image style={{}} source={require('./Images/Ellipse 36.png')} />
          <Image style={{position:'absolute',top:14,left:14}} source={require('./Images/Asset 65.png')} />
      </View>
      <View style={{position:'absolute', width:42,height:42,right:20,top:(height-42)/3,zIndex:3}}>
          <Image style={{}} source={require('./Images/Ellipse 36.png')} />
          <Image style={{position:'absolute',top:10,left:12}} source={require('./Images/Asset 66.png')} />
      </View>
      <View><TopToolbar text='Swipe' navigator={this.props.navigator} user={this.props.user}/></View>
      <ScrollView style={{zIndex:1,}}><Inders style={{flex: 1}} navigator={this.props.navigator} credentials={this.props.credentials}/></ScrollView>
      <View style={{zIndex:0,}}><BottomToolbar user={this.props.user} navigator={this.props.navigator} credentials={this.props.credentials}/></View>
    </View>
    )
  }
```

Where Inders is a component.
I tried changing the order of the components but it didn't work.
What is the way to make a button "float" from another component?

Comment: Could you post an example of your React Native code. The styles probably have very little to do with it.

Comment: What part of the code would help? The mark up?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#zindex

Comment: @YinonEliraz yes

Comment: Added the render function.@JasonGaare, zIndex did not work here.

Comment: @YinonEliraz could you send a full screen shot, rather than that clipped view?

Comment: @JasonGaare here is a full screenshot, sorry it's huge.

Comment: @YinonEliraz try adding the zIndex to the entire toolbar, not just the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to wrap the toolbar in another View, so that the new View is the parent of the element that you want to "float".

Answer (score 0):

Open inspector in the Dev tools menu and find out who cut your component, I also like to set backgroundColor to see their position, it make solve this type of bugs mack more easy.

Comment: I know who cut my component, I am trying to fix it.